# Does the skeleton suit do anything special?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

The skeleton suit, costing 9999 coins, has been taunting me for a while.

I don't see why this suit costs so much? It doesn't seem to be a reference to anything, and other suits seem to cap at 2k coins.

So does the skeleton suit do anything special? Or is it just a suit that is gonna give you bragging rights?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.gamesradar.com/super-mario-odyssey-skeleton-costume-guide/), the skeleton suit does nothing noteworthy other than turn Mario into a skeleton.

> Spoiler alert. Donning your very expensive skeleton costume does absolutely nothing. Zip. Nada. All those coins for a Halloween costume.

A video of this can be found in [this article](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2017/11/01/heres-what-super-mario-odysseys-most-expensive-suit-looks-like-in-action-skeleton-bones.aspx).

Comment: It changes a sentence in Bowser's dialogue before fighting him at the wedding chapel.

Comment: Given @Diriector_Doc 's comment and the other answer below, I would say this answer isn't actually correct, despite citing sources.

Comment: @Fredy31 Also, I went and re-fought Bowser at the chapel, confirming the above comment.

Answer (score 4):

Wearing it does actually let you go in the room in the sand kingdom that the game normaly expects you to use the poncho to get into (the day of the dead skeleton guy does say you have to “dress like one of us” :)) but beyond that it’s just cosmetic and not really worth the hours spent grinding for it imho.

Comment: I went to the Sand Kingdom to verify this. The Tostarenan guarding the room does not change his dialogue though. Perhaps it truly is a poncho, shining some light on the "cutting-edge... something" which makes the costume "work".

Comment: Furthermore, I traveled to other places in which a door is guarded by that kingdom's citizen who will only grant entry if you wear a specific outfit; wearing the appropriate hat and the skeleton suit leads the citizen to comment that your hat is right, but the rest of your outfit isn't right.

Answer (score -1):

I love this suit. It does nothing special, but I love it. I purchased this suit and I look crazy when I talk to Luigi. Luigi freaks out before saying "hey, do you want to connect to the internet and play balloon world?"